# Using regex to check for no characters before another

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to select any letter character (a-z) with no numbers in front of it. For example:

```
2x+a-3p returns a
a+b-c+d returns a,b,c,d
7g+8k returns nothing
```

I'm attempting to use regex for this so that I can use the expression in python but I can't find the solution.

I am using Python 3.10.4 if that is necessary.

Comment: You can use `(?![0-9]).([a-zA-z])` and then look at the capturing group to get the letter.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  In the future, you should put in your question what attempts you've made so far.  Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\d)[a-z]
```

Translates exactly into "*any letter character (a-z) with no numbers in front of it*".

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/IpBykQ/1).

Answer (score 1):

A first pass attempt would be

```py
p = re.compile(r'[^0-9]([a-z])')
```

This would get a lower-case letter preceded by a character which is not a digit.  However, You would miss any letters which occurred at the beginning of a line since there would be no character preceding the letter.  So, you can instead do

```py
p = re.compile(r'(?:[^0-9]|^)([a-z])')
```